# Global Access to Class instance - Optimal design approach?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, class, global-variables

OK, here is my situation and I'm really not sure on which design approach to use. So, I'd be glad to read some input on my particular case...

**The scenario :**

- I've got a tab-based application
- Initially we create an instance of `NSWindowController` (e.g. `MyDocumentManager`) which takes care of the tab creation/manipulation
- Each tab contains (= is attached to) an instance of `MyDocument`

Now, I'm about to implement the menu actions.

- For each menu there is a separate Menu Controller (actually a subclass of `NSObject` grouping all relevant functions), e.g. `MyFileMenuController`
- File Menu's actions are linked to actions in a `MyFileMenuController` object, via Interface Builder

**The question :**

- How is it possible that `MyFileMenuController` *"knows"* about `MyDocumentManager` (created in my `AppDelegate.m`), so that we can access current document details and perform all relevant actions? Any ideas? Which approach is preferable?

---

**My ideas :**

- Passing object from class to class (not sounding that great)
- Singletons (although I've honestly never used them, and do not know whether/how it could be my particular case)
- Notifications & Notification Listeners
- (Looking at it from the opposite side, though not sure) Delegate methods

Answer (score 0):

OK (not sure if that's the best way to do it), but this is what I decided to do :

```
[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate] MyDocumentManager]
```

So, as long as an object is part of my AppDelegate, this way I can access it from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would make an initial UIViewController linked to appDelegate.rootViewController.

In this new view controller (just call it "mainViewController") I would put my tabBar and the menuController.

I understand your interface is similar to facebook with a leftBarbutton which makes horizontal scroll and discover the menu. So in the selector for this leftBarButton I would call a method like:

```
- (void)discoverMenuForDocument:(MyDocument*)document {
    // Set menu configuration for specific document
    // Make animation to discover menu
}
```

Where document could be something like:

```
self.selectedViewController (<-- You cand make this in several ways depending on your code...)
```

Realize that (MyDocument*) is not an object but just a reference, so in my opinion there isn't any problem doing this.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Although I definitely cannot spot the connection between your answer and my question... :S (btw, I'm not talking about Cocoa Touch - the question was about Cocoa/OSX).

Comment: I'm sorry I was thinking in a common pattern in iOS.